# Compile ruby script into exe?

Tags: ruby, compilation, exe, watir

Is it possible to compile a ruby script into an .exe on Windows? I have searched everywhere and I've tried the following (It looked like RubyScript2EXE, Shoes and Crate all seemed dead or abandoned.):

1. http://ocra.rubyforge.org/
2. http://exerb.sourceforge.jp/index.en.html

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 on Windows 7 Ultimate (64bit.) from a clean system I do this:

1. Install RubyInstaller 1.8.7-p358 from rubyinstaller.org
2. gem install watir
3. gem install ocra
4. git clone git://github.com/snaury/exerb-mingw.git
5. cd exerb-mingw
6. ruby setup.rb

I have a fairly simple script that does this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://slashdot.org'
```

When I run Ocra I don't get any error messages, and nothing happens:

```
ocra --output test.exe test.rb
=== Loading script to check dependencies
```

Exerb seems like a better solution since it compiles to rbc, and it does actually do something:

```
ruby -r exerb/mkexy test.rb
# Window pops up and after I close it it writes out test.exy
C:\Users\jonathan\dev\Citation>exerb test.exy
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/exerb/recipe.rb:146:in `add_file_entry': test.
exy: no such file -- C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-api-1.4.8-x86-mingw32/lib/win32/ruby18/win32/api.so (RuntimeError)
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/exerb/recipe.rb:86:in `create_archive'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/exerb/recipe.rb:85:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/exerb/recipe.rb:85:in `create_archive'
    from C:/Ruby187/bin/exerb.bat:67:in `main'
    from C:/Ruby187/bin/exerb.bat:196
```

So it can't find win32/api.so. When I look in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/exerb/recipe.rb it looks like gems are not in the search path:

```
DIR: C:/Users/jonathan/dev/Citation
DIR: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
DIR: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i386-msvcrt
DIR: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby
DIR: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
DIR: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i386-msvcrt
DIR: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
DIR: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8
DIR: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32
DIR: .
```

So after digging around I found out you can add search paths in the exy file like so:

```
path:
  - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/
  - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems
```

After this it does show these paths in search_path, but it still gives me the same error. Obviously there must be some way to get rubygems paths to be included in the exy?

So, how does someone build a .exe on Windows these days?

I made some progress with Exerb, I found out you can run mkexy with the -rrubygems option to pull this in. And this works GREAT for most ruby projects. I've tried it for a few ruby scripts that use a number of different libraries without problems. For example:

```
mkexy -rrubygems test.rb
exerb test.exy
test.exe === WORKS!
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for watir. When I run an .exe built with watir I get the following:

```
s4t-utils/claims.rb:24:in `user_is_bewildered': Error in the default values: :br
```

owser's value must be one of 'safari', 'firefox', or 'ie', and '' doesn't look r
ight. (StandardError)

Comment: Perhaps you can try this: http://johnallen.us/?p=278

Comment: Did you see a console spawned by Ocra? If you compiled a .rb instead of a .rbw you should have seen one.

Comment: I actually didn't see anything, no window, nothing. Maybe it popped up the error message mentioned in the johnallen.us link and then died? I'll experiment more with ocra tomorrow and update this question.

Comment: Quick update: I tried ocra for 1.9.3, no luck. Also it seems like bizarre things are happening with it. Like, for example, I changed the code to load "http://google.com" and it still opened IE with Slashdot.

Comment: I did make some progress with Exerb, this page (in Japanese) ([link]http://up-cat.net/?page=wxRuby%20%2B%20Exerb%202009[/link]) mentions using -rrubygems as an option to mkexy. I tried this and it works great! It generated the .exe file just fine. However, when I try to run it I get the error: `s4t-utils/claims.rb:24:in `user_is_bewildered': Error in the default values: :br
owser's value must be one of 'safari', 'firefox', or 'ie', and '' doesn't look r
ight. (StandardError)`

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/rdp/ruby_tutorials_core/wiki/ruby-talk-faq#wiki-ruby_to_exe was a list of them at one time.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the answer! The error message about missing win32/api.so is because mkexy is creating an invalid exy file. Checking line 303 it looks like it formats it incorrectly. I corrected it to:

```
win32/api.so:
    file: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-api-1.4.8-x86-mingw32/lib/win32/ruby18/win32/api.so
    type: extension-library
```

And now it works. When I run it I still get the message about the "user is bewildered". The solution to this is to add:

```
Watir::Browser.default = "ie"
```

to the script. Next there are still a few missing libraries that exerb is not adding. I haven't figured out yet how to make them appear but you can just copy them to the exe's path and it works.

```
cp -r C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-api-1.4.8-x86-mingw32/lib/win32/ .
cp -r C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir .
```

Problem goes away and the script executes! Also, you can use UPX to pack it.

upx --best test.exe

It becomes a 500kb file! With UPX + this extra stuff the whole app would be a mere 650kb or so. No script I could make with ocra was less than 1Mb. Not to mention the fact that it's really buggy and leaves .rb files in random locations if it crashes.

I think with some tweaking of the .exy file I can make it include all the files. I'll update this question with the answer if I find it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Ocra documentation, you can prevent your app from running during ocra compilation by checking the `Ocra` constant:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

if not defined?(Ocra)
  browser = Watir::Browser.new
  browser.goto 'http://slashdot.org'
end
```

Perhaps this will help get through the compile.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is so light-weight that I never minded installing it on another system. I can see wanting to avoid dealing with all the devkits and whatnot, but you can create an image and copy that around with a couple minor changes to the system environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and as August 2014 this is the best I could find:

This link has a nice history on the main projects that did/do or otherwise contributed:
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables

As far as I can tell there are two main ones, OCRA (works just on windows) and Releasy (based on OCRA but works on macs and linux as far as I can tell)

https://github.com/larsch/ocra/

https://github.com/Spooner/releasy/