# how to make command line program without using language name first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line

When I run a ruby program from the command line, I have to add "ruby" at the beginning of the command (ex. 'ruby hangman.rb'). My question is, how do I make a command line program without having to use 'ruby' in front to run the program. I know this has to be possible because RoR is written in ruby and you don't have to run "ruby rails [command]", you just run "rails". Any Ideas?

Comment: If you are on windows, you may want to compile ruby. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998819/compile-ruby-script-into-exe

Comment: This is documented heavily. You'll want to look up discussions on `bin` — RubyGems has a nice guide on making an executable, http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable

Comment: Rails is a gem. Gems are generally run from somewhere in your PATH. See also `gem env`.

Comment: It would appear I have some research to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be to bundle it as a Gem - this allows to [define an executable](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable).

Another a bit "hacky" option would be to create a hangman.bat file that would just call `ruby hangman.rb`

Note that both cases would still require ruby to be installed on any target computer.